# Amazon API display all product from specific category/subcategory based on BrowseNode

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I have a plan to make web based Amazon API, the problem that I facing is when I need to display all product (its fine if its just first 10 page) on specific category. Been try using format like this

```
$query = array( 'Operation'         => 'ItemSearch', 
                'BrowseNode'         => '83451031', 
                //'SearchIndex'          => 'Apparel',
                'ResponseGroup'      => 'Small',
                'ItemPage'=>'1');
```

While 83451031 is Node from Apparel on UK locale. It won't display all item on that category IF I didn't add SearchIndex => 'Apparel' active on it. Meanwhile the search only depend on that Node ID. Meanwhile if i put SearchIndex => 'All' it wont work either

Anyone can help? Or there is other way to display all product based on specific category and/or sub category

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Product Advertising API as a limit on the number of pages. For the 'ItemSearch' operation this limit is 10, so you can only access from pages 1 to 10. The solution is to modify the search parameters, so the api returns fewer responses. This link describes how the pagination and sorting of the api results works: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingandSortingThroughResults.html

Comment: Hi Nadir, its fine for me for the result only 10 first page like I said above, the problem that I face is how to display the latest product on specific category, for example clothing category (browser node is 83451031), I want to get list of all product in first page on that category, only based on browser node id, how I do that?